# How to convert strings to bigInt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, biginteger, bigint

I need to convert a string to BigInt like `BigInteger` in Javascript

Example

```
var reqId = "78099864177253771992779766288266836166272662";
var result = parseInt(reqId);
document.write(result);
```

Resultant value not matching since JavaScript only allows integers up to (2^53)-1.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: I see no java here... why do you tag this as a java question??

Comment: How to use that other packages to do Infinite precision, do u have any idea ?

Answer (score 61):

[`BigInt`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint) is now a native JavaScript language feature. It's at Stage 3 in the TC39 process and it's shipping in V8 v6.7 and Chrome 67.

To turn a string containing a valid numeric literal into a `BigInt`, use the global `BigInt` function:

```
const string = '78099864177253771992779766288266836166272662';
BigInt(string);
// 78099864177253771992779766288266836166272662n
```

If you just want to hardcode the numeric value into your code, there is no need to convert from a string; use a `BigInt` literal instead:

```
const value = 78099864177253771992779766288266836166272662n;
```

Comment: @Centell, That's because you're using a numeric literal instead of a string literal. The moment the non-BigInt numeric literal is created, you've already lost precision. See https://v8.dev/features/bigint#api

Answer (score 5):

You can use a JavaScript lib called **BigInteger.js** for the purpose.it is an arbitrary-length integer library for Javascript, allows arithmetic operations on integers of unlimited size, notwithstanding memory and time limitations.[This lib can be download from this link](http://peterolson.github.io/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js).Like `var largeNumber = bigInt("75643564363473453456342378564387956906736546456235345");`
You can find documentation of lib here https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html):

```
var reqId = "78099864177253771992779766288266836166272662";
var myBigNumber = math.bignumber(reqId);
var res = math.add(myBigNumber, 1);
console.log(myBigNumber.toString());
// 7.8099864177253771992779766288266836166272662e+43
console.log(res.toString());
// 7.8099864177253771992779766288266836166272663e+43
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of creating a BigInt, in this jskata you can see them and try it out https://jskatas.org/katas/es11/language/bigint/basics/#creating-one-can-be-done-in-multiple-ways

```
      const fourtyTwoAsBigInt = 42n;
      assert.strictEqual(BigInt("42"), fourtyTwoAsBigInt);
```