# Convert string to integer BigInt

Tags: javascript, numbers, integer, rounding, bigint

This may be a recurring question.
I need to convert a string to an integer. But JS does this:
`parseInt("2166767952358020110") ⇒ 2166767952358020000`

I know why it happens but how to correctly convert a string to an integer?
`BigInt()` doesn't fit in my case.

Comment: What about `BigInt("2166767952358020110")` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert strings to bigint in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826748/how-to-convert-strings-to-bigint-in-javascript)

Comment: the number is too big...

Comment: Ordinary numbers in JavaScript are always 64-bit floating-point values. The value Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER tells you the maximum integer value representable, and it's smaller than your value. In modern JavaScript environments you may be able to use `BigInt(yourString)` to make a "big integer" value.

Comment: @NickParsons, in my case I can't use BigInt because it adds "n" at the end, but I need a normal integer

Comment: There's a very famous implementation of Big Number in JS named "bn.js"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your number is above the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, you can't directly convert the string to a number without having some errors.

I suggest you to use the [BigNumber](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js) library which has been done for this purpose

```
const BN = require('bn.js');

const number = new BN('2166767952358020110', 10);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution and it returns "1e11e7f8ff00140e"..
Seems I can't get pure integer above 53 bites

Comment: You will never have a pure integer above the limit but bignumber is providing you some helpers to perform the calculation you expect